# Use of the word "behind" in this context

Tags: word-usage

> I think John tried to tell me something **behind** his smile.
>
> This advertisement seems to tell us something perverse **behind** its
> apparent comicality.

Is this a correct use of the word "behind", associated with the verb "tell"? Does it sound natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes those examples are correct and they do sound natural. Something can be hiding *behind* something shown. A smile is shown in front that can look friendly, but unfriendly thoughts and feelings can be hidden *behind* it.

The word *under* can be used in a similar way.

[Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/behind_1):

> 7   **used for stating hidden facts**

> 7a **used for saying that someone’s appearance or behaviour hides their real character or feelings**
> *Behind her quiet shy manner there is a passionate spirit.
>
> It was an evil business conducted behind a show of respectability.*

> 7b **used for talking about the real facts of a situation that people do not know**
> *Parents are demanding to know the truth behind these disturbing rumours.
>
> the terrible story behind the fur trade*